# A weird error of variable not defined inside a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a helper function called `flattenErrorObj` inside the register.js which contains redux actions. This helper method just flatten a object which contains key & array values.

```
function flattenErrorObj(errObj) {
    errorList = []
    
    for(const prop in errObj){
      
      errObj[prop].forEach((item)=>{
        errorList.push(prop +': '+item)
      });
    }
    return errorList;
}

export function registerUser(payload) {
    return (dispatch) => {

        dispatch(requestRegister());


        if (payload) {
            axios({
                url: '/users/create',
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data"
                },
                data: payload
            }).then(res => {
                dispatch(receiveRegister());
                
                successToast(res.data.message)

            }).catch(err => {
                console.log('Error',err.response.data);
                errorToast(flattenErrorObj(err.response.data))
            })

        } else {
            dispatch(registerError('Something was wrong. Try again'));
        }
    };
}
```

I am getting this weird error,

> Failed to compile
>
> ./src/actions/register.js
> Line 28:   'errorList' is not defined no-undef
> Line 33:   'errorList' is not defined  no-undef
> Line 36: 'errorList' is not defined  no-undef

Even if I change the name of `errorList` variable I am still getting this error,saying that variable is not defined.I am new to reactjs, So am I doing anything wrong here?Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try actually declaring `errorList`, i.e. `const errorList = []` so it is defined? This is a vanilla javascript error.

Comment: if it is running in strict mode (which it probably is), then you actually need to define the variable, using keywords like `var`, `let` or `const`. AKA, the compiler is right

Comment: fu*k. I wrote that code in separate file to test & it worked their without the let or const,then i added that code with react & it started throwing that error.I had some bad habbit of writting js that way or may I mainly use python that's why. Btw thanks @DrewReese

Comment: Welcome. Not my downvote, btw, I only voted to close as "unreproducible or caused by typo". Cheers and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running react in strict mode. You can not create variable without keywords. Use
`let errorList = [];`

Answer (score 0):

To define a variable, you must use `var`, `let` or `const`.
Please refer https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp.

Use one of the following

`var errorList = []`

`let errorList = []`

`const errorList = []`